# Generating a List of object properties from a pre-existing list VB.Net

Tags: python, vb.net, linq

With a python background, I've become rather accustomed to using lines like

```
print(" ".join({x.name for x in my_list}))
```

where

```
{x.name for x in my_list}
```

is a list/array containing the name property of each of the objects in my_list.

I'm looking to do something similar in VB.Net, I know this is possible using a longer section of code like:

```
Dim str1 = ""
For each item in myList
   str1 &= item.name & " "
Next
```

But I'd much prefer a simpler solution as I'll be doing this a lot, and I've heard there's similar notation possible using LINQ.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you talking about [IEnumerable(Of T).Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) function. Which you can use for mapping collection of one type to collection of another type.

```
Dim combinedNames As String = String.Join(" ", myList.Select(Function(item) item.Name))
```

So equivalent for python's `{x.name for x in my_list}` in vb.net will be

```
Dim names = myList.Select(Function(item) item.Name)

Dim builder = new StringBuilder()
For Each name in names
    builder.Append(name)
    builder.Append(" ")
Next

Dim allNames = builder.ToString()
```

Notice that `Select` function return `IEnumerable(Of T)` type.

Answer (score 1):

The VB.NET equivalent of your code is:

```
Debug.Print(String.Join(" ", From x In my_list Select x.Name))
```

The "query comprehension" form `From x In my_list Select x.Name` when compiled is identical to the extension function form `my_list.Select(Function(x) x.Name)`.  It's up to your preference which syntax you use.

Comment: Just to clarify, query "translated" in extension functions calls, then it will be compiled.